# How to pass javascript value to html href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass the value of finalName in the href attribute inside the body of html. How can I do so?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        var url = window.location.search;
        var val = getParameter('n');
        var finalName = "";
        if( val == false ) {
            var a= prompt("Enter your name & see the magic", "");
            if(a){
                window.location.href = '?n='+a;
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = a ;
                finalName = a;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = val;
        }
</script>

<body>
<a class="footerbtn" href="whatsapp://send?text= send you special surprise message%0A%0ATouch this blue line %0Aenter your name %0A http://magic.pagalworld.buzz/?n=" 
  onclick="location.href=this.href+finalName;return false;"><img width="25px" height="25px" src="wp.png"/><b style="font-size: 15px;"> Click Here to Share on Whatsapp</b> <img width="25px" height="25px" src="wp.png"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you assign to `window.location` it reloads the page, and scripts on the current page stop running.

Comment: this.href+'?data='+finalName

Comment: If you change the `window.location` passing your variable in a GET request, you'll need some server language to process this request. There's no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the variable accessible by using window.finalName.
eg:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        var url = window.location.search;
        var val = getParameter('n');
        window.finalName = "";
        if( val == false ) {
            var a= prompt("Enter your name & see the magic", "");
            if(a){
                window.location.href = '?n='+a;
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = a ;
                window.finalName = a;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = val;
        }
</script>
```

```html
<html>


<body>
<a class="footerbtn" href="whatsapp://send?text= send you special surprise message%0A%0ATouch this blue line %0Aenter your name %0A http://magic.pagalworld.buzz/?n=" 
  onclick="location.href=this.href+finalName;return false;"><img width="25px" height="25px" src="wp.png"/><b style="font-size: 15px;"> Click Here to Share on Whatsapp</b> <img width="25px" height="25px" src="wp.png"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a global variable, they're automatically properties of `window`.